# Iphone Dropped and will not turn on

Tags: battery, jailbreak

Recently i dropped my phone, with no visibal damage i carried on using it. After a while the phone began 'searching' for a network, i turned the phone off and on again in hope that this would work but the phone wouldn't turn back on. When i got home a put the phone on charge and it showed the apple logo, as if it was turning back on but then went blank again. The phone repeats this process whislt only on charge, when i take the phone of of charge it will not switch on or anything.

- Prior to dropping my phone i replaced the battery as tit died for no reason, this worked fine the the new battery was working however if i were to shake the phone i could fell something moving inside, i think the battery is loose and that might be the problem but would like some extra advice
- Also the phone is jailbroken if that can effect the outcomes in any way
- NOTE - The phone does not turn on at all so i cannot factory reset and neither can i get the phone to enter recovery/DFU mode.

Thanks for any help given,

Luke

Comment: Take it to a shop that can fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to hold the lock and home button at the same time for about 10-15 seconds and it will turn back on.